# One word for a man who feels vulnerable about his wife

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What would we call a man who is always suspecting, distrustful and worried about his wife being wooed by other men? He considers his wife naive and the world (other men) as predators in waiting.

It would definitely have negative meanings since the wife is just the opposite, i.e. she is unsuspecting.

Comment: You have "vulnerable"....

Comment: There is always "cuckold", for someone who has reason to be distrustful.

Comment: Possessive, overbearing, irrational,narcistic...

Comment: Doesn't "married" cover it? ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you for the "words"...I would vote for "possessive and insecure".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Insecure" is a pretty accurate word. Being insecure about your relationship can mean you are constantly worried and suspicious that your partner is attracted or involved with someone else. Bear in mind that insecurity has a wider application and can go beyond a mistrusting feeling in a ***relationship***(see below).

Another accurate example would be "Jealous".

However, ***jealousy*** is a much more temporary condition/feeling often caused by ***insecurity***, which is a long term (and more concerning) personality trait. All men can experience jealousy, but insecure men are affected more frequently and severely.

Comment: +1 for _insecure_. It also covers being _distrustful_ in a broader sense.

Comment: *Insecure* is a fine answer, and I will vote it up! It seems that representing *jealousy* as a temporary effect of *insecurity* is an arbitrary determination that has no basis in either of the words. One could make just as strong a case for *jealousy* being the cause of *insecurity*. Words are not wives and  we are not in a win-lose competition here, so I will demonstrate *security* in my answer without sacrificing my legitimate *jealousy for it*.

Comment: @GoodA.M. I think you are under the impression that my answer was in some way rejecting your answer. I can assure you this is not the case and there is no need to compete against different answers as each are equally valuable. Regarding the first part of your comment, psychologically, jealousy IS a temporary emotion but in some cases it can linger and lead to prolong effects such as an insecure personality. However, insecure people are more likely to have feelings of jealousy in a relationship(It's a "chicken and egg issue").

Comment: Not feeling rejected at all :-); our answers complement one another. Your observation of the psychological connection between the words is legitimate, but I am suggesting a *complex cause effect relationship* or **feedback loop** between jealousy and insecurity (see logical fallacies: http://onegoodmove.org/fallacy/complex.htm) I use the coexistence of legitimate jealousy and security in my own answer as an instance where *jealousy* (the positive sense of fond ardent zeal) is not a temporary effect of *insecurity*.

Comment: No, jealousy is not necessarily a temporary effect of insecurity, but having an insecure personality can bring about feelings of jealousy in a relationship. However, I added the word "often" in my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would argue that while *jealousy* is an emotion, which comes and goes as other emotions do, when you describe someone as *a jealous man* you are not describing a man currently experiencing jealousy, but rather someone prone to doing so.

Comment: That is correct. Jealousy (depending on how it's used) can be used to refer to a personality trait rather a temporary emotion. Nonetheless, jealousy is a more precise characteristic which can be part of a bigger more comprehensive trait such as insecurity (which has a wider application).

Comment: It's a pleasure to make the acquaintance of some real Neanderthal Men! The *personality trait* of jealousy is established by nurturing the **emotion** of jealousy over an extended period of time. Eventually that constant emotional experience becomes a defining element of his identity. An insecure man **constantly experiences** the emotion of insecurity inordinately, just like a jealous man **constantly experiences** the emotion of jealousy inordinately. Remind me not to hire either of you to be a psychotherapist :-) *Insecure* is a very good answer; you could *feel **more** secure* in it.

Comment: Reminder(as requested): Don't hire either of us to be a  psychotherapist!
I believe the comments have reached a point were they are all stating the same fact but from different viewpoints. Therefore, I think they are all correct and this discussion has long surpassed the scope of this community :)

Answer (score 7):

[*Protective*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protective) might be a good word:

> 1.1 Having or showing a strong wish to protect someone or something:
>
> From the Verb form *protect*:
>
> Keep safe from harm or injury:

If you wish to stress the fact that his primary *[mistrust](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mistrust)* is toward men, who might use her *unsuspecting naivete* to harm her, this would be a good choice as the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=protect&searchmode=none) implies placing himself **in front** of his wife, between her and those who would take advantage of her:

> mid-15c., from Latin protectus, past participle of protegere "to
>   protect, **cover in front**" (see protection). International economics
>   sense from 1789. Related: Protected; protecting.
>
> [protection](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=protection&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.) Look up protection at Dictionary.com mid-14c.,
>   "shelter, defense; keeping, guardianship;" late 14c. as "that which
>   protects," from Old French proteccion "protection, **shield**" (12c.) and
>   directly from Late Latin protectionem (nominative protectio) "a
>   covering over," noun of action from past participle stem of protegere
>   "protect, cover in front," from pro- "in front" + tegere "to cover"

***Over-protective*** projects the negative emotion more forcefully.

[*Jealous*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jealous?searchDictCode=all) seems like a good descriptor for the more general feeling toward his wife. The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=jealous&searchmode=none) shows that the connotations of the word may be broader than our common usage:

> c.1200, gelus, later jelus (early 14c.), "**possessive** and **suspicious**,"
>   originally in the context of sexuality or romance; in general use late
>   14c.;
>
> also in a more positive sense, "**fond**, **amorous**, **ardent**," from
>   c.1300, from Old French jalos "**keen**, **zealous**; **avaricious**; jealous"
>   (12c., Modern French jaloux),
>
> from Late Latin zelosus, from zelus
>   "zeal," from Greek zelos, sometimes "jealousy," but more often in a
>   good sense ("**emulation**, **rivalry**, **zeal**"). See zeal.
>
> In biblical
>   language (early 13c.) "**tolerating no unfaithfulness**." Most of the
>   words for 'envy' ... had from the outset a hostile force, based on
>   'look at' (with malice), 'not love,' etc. Conversely, most of those
>   which became distinctive terms for 'jealousy' were originally used
>   also in a good sense, 'zeal, emulation.' [Buck, pp.1138-9]
>
> Among the
>   ways to express this in other tongues are Swedish svartsjuka,
>   literally "black-sick," from phrase bara svarta strumpor "wear black
>   stockings," also "be jealous." Danish skinsyg "jealous," literally
>   "skin-sick," is from skind "hide, skin" said to be explained by
>   Swedish dialectal expression fa skinn "receive a refusal in
>   courtship."

The construction *He's jealous of ...* would tend to put more stress on the suspicious rivalry he feels toward the seduction of other men. Using *He's jealous for ...* might put more stress on the fond amorous zeal he feels toward her.

Comment: To be blunt, *protective* seems too positive in connotation. The question explicitly requests something with a negative connotation. Consider making the negativity explicit by going with ***over**-protective*?

Comment: The answer mentions that the **negative** emotion of mistrust is directed at the men, but thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

> This is a man who fears (not feels)and he is a [paranoid (TFD)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paranoid) person
>   who suffers from paranoia, the unreasonable fear or irrational belief
>   that other people are plotting to harm him or her.

Comment: *Paranoid* is a good suggestion (I was going to add it myself if I didn’t see it listed), but this is a difficult answer to read. I think something may have gotten messed up when you copied this?

Answer (score -1):

http://www.thefreedictionary.com

anxious:

1. Uneasy and apprehensive about an uncertain event or matter; worried.
2. Attended with, showing, or causing anxiety: spent an anxious night waiting for the test results.
3. Usage Problem Eagerly or earnestly desirous.

Answer (score -2):

This is the defining characteristic of Shakespeare's [Othello](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Othello) (and his wife is also innocent and unsuspecting). If you said "an Othello type", in an appropriate context, it could convey what you need.